# Finding out which EF operation is blocking

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm getting

> System.NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this
>   context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use
>   'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed
>   before calling another method on this context. Any instance members
>   are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Totally get it, I know how to solve it in theory, that's not the problem. But for the life of me I can't find the actual operation causing the block.

This is in production, under medium loads. I can't reproduce it while debugging. So I need some way of throwing information about uncompleted EF requests.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is totally clear to you, but "the actual transaction causing the block" is not the "uncompleted EF request". The "transaction" (more precisely: the context method being executed) causing the block is the operation that will complete. When you get the exception there's no way to find out which operation this is. You can of course find the interrupted operation (that causes the exception) in the stack trace. Nevertheless, I hope I'm wrong, but this exception seems to be the tell-tale of a design flaw: long context lifespans.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I was careless with my choice of words. And you are correct also that the root of the problem was a design flaw, caused by using the same context in a `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` which unbeknownst to me has rather long lifespan. I discovered this only after assigning a guid upon context creation and logging its use.

Comment: Is there a way for you to fix the lifespan problem? I think you should create a new context each time the OnAuthorization(Async) method runs.

Comment: Yeah, that was my solution as well. For the moment I'm setting a Unity container on the filter at creation - for setting up the repositories - but I'll swap it out with a delegate for the sake of pattern adherance.

Comment: Why don't you post code of your `AuthorizationFilterAttribute`?

Comment: Will you consider updating code on production to log debug info?

Comment: @AkashKava Safety concerns, primarily.

Comment: @LeonidUsov I log in production code.

Comment: So you could enable entity framework query logging into a file named after the session id, so that you know to distinguish between queries for concurrent users

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure, but maybe [DNT Profiler](https://github.com/VahidN/DNTProfiler) help you for monitoring and profiling EF opereations.